# Issue running grunt command Error: Cannot find module 'has'

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am facing errors with grunt commands for a dojo project with following version of node, npm and grunt-cli

grunt-cli version : 0.1.13
node version : 6.17.1
npm version : 3.10.10

Getting below error when running grunt command after npm install.

```
PS C:\workspace\ui\test\ui> grunt
module.js:478
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'has'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\6110853\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.17.1\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\is-core-module\index.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
```

Tried npm install after deleting node_modules.
Tried installing has module before running npm-install
grunt-cli has been installed globally and I see the required module is present in node_module but we still get module not found error.
Can anybody suggest how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by incompatible dependencies. I encountered the same error on grunt@1.3.0. Upgrading node/npm tools to newer versions solved the problem in my case:

node@6.3.1 -> node@12.14.0

npm@3.10.3 -> npm@6.13.4